# C# GDI Moving an ellipse from one point to another and back

Tags: c#, gdi

I am creating an application which similates a car game, It uses two keys, the left and right keys. I am using an ellipse and moving it in both directions. When I start the application and moving the ellipse to the right key it works fine when I press the left key it freezes, and I am using another ellipse which must be constantly moving down.
Below are the two functions that I use to move the ellipse. and the key_down event for the form:

```
 public void MoveLeft()
    {

        if (startPoint.Y > 100)
        {
            startPoint.Y = 1;
        }
        while (startPoint.Y > 1)
        {


            graphics.Clear(BackColor);
            if (startPoint.Y > this.ClientSize.Height)
                startPoint.Y = 0;
            startPoint.Y += 5;
            graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(carPoint, new Size(100, 100)));
            graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), new Rectangle(carPoint, new Size(100, 100)));
            Move();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);


        }
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
       while (startPoint.Y > 1)
        {
            if (startPoint.Y > this.ClientSize.Height)
                startPoint.Y = 0;
            startPoint.Y += 5;
            carPoint = new Point(100, 250);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(carPoint, new Size(100, 100)));
            graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), new Rectangle(carPoint, new Size(100, 100)));
            Move();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            graphics.Clear(BackColor);
        }
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(startPoint, new Size(100, 100)));
        graphics.FillEllipse(new TextureBrush(image), new Rectangle(startPoint, new Size(100, 100)));
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.Right:
                {
                    moveCar = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MoveRight));
                    moveCar.Start();

                }
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
                {
                    if (moveCar != null)
                    {
                        moveCar.Abort();
                        moveCar = null;
                    }
                    moveCar = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MoveLeft));
                    moveCar.Start();
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: My first feeling is that you are not using the right tool. Sure you can achieve your goal, but XNA framework is far more suited for building game than old-school gdi drawing. Even WPF can be better. Are you sticked to windows form + gdi, or can you use another technology ?

Comment: I do have an option of using other technologies, but Am trying to learn GDI as much as I can

Comment: gdi is a declining technology. Don't know your motivations and/or requirements, but I'd advise to move to newer technologies.

Comment: Neither the Graphics class nor a Windows window is thread-safe.  The kind of trouble you'll run into ranges somewhere between painting artifacts, deadlock and hard crashes.  Deadlock here by the sound of it.  You'll need to implement the typical game-loop instead.  Google "winforms game loop".

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with the code.

Firstly, you probably want to be painting only on the On_Paint event. When that event is fired, you can simply paint your car where it's supposed to be. There is a `PaintEventArgs` that gets passed to the On_Paint event, and that contains a Graphics object.

In your movement function, it's a good thing to create a thread for moving the car, but you don't want to recreate threads each time a key is pressed. Instead, you can keep a direction state on the Form like `bool IsMovingLeft` or `int Velocity`. Then you create one thread which updates the position based on the state of that variable.

It would also be good to force the Form/Control to redraw itself once you've made an update to the position of the car. You can use `this.Refresh()` to accomplish that.